# A map from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1)$ such that the image of every open interval in $(0,1)$ is $(0,1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Can we have a map from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1)$ such that the image of every open interval in $(0,1)$ is all of $(0,1)$ ?

Comment: This is more or less the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186427/function-whose-image-of-every-open-interval-is-infty-infty/186434#186434

Comment: Try something using $\sin\frac1x$ or its translates perhaps.

Comment: If you want to explicitly use Chris Eagle's example $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, you could always say $g(x) = 1+\frac1{\pi}\arctan(\pi f(\tan(\pi(x-\frac12))))$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Using $g(x)=f(x)$ where it makes sense and $g(x)=0.5$ where it doesn't would be significantly less crazy.

Comment: @ChrisEagle that indeed makes sense and seems much less crazy.

Comment: A suitable modification of [Example 2.25](http://books.google.com/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC&pg=PA31&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) in Gelbaum and Olmsted's *Counterexamples in Analysis* will work.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. My favorite, though it takes a little cleaning in the corners is this one. Let $x\in (0,1)$ and express it in base $3$. If there are an infinite number of $2$'s in the expansion, set $f(x)=x$ and ignore it. Otherwise, cut off all the leading digits through the last $2$ and read the resulting number in binary to get $f(x)$. Given any $y \in (0,1)$ expressed in binary and an interval $(a,b)$ we can find $c \in (a,b)$ expressed in ternary ending in $2$ that we can append $y$ to and stay in $(a,b)$

Comment: This reminds me a lot of [Conway's base 13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function).