# Is there a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that every non-empty open interval is mapped onto $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

> I wonder  whether there is a function $f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ with the folowing characteristic? 
>
> for every two real numbers $\alpha,\beta,\alpha\lt\beta$,
>
> $$\{f(x):x\in(\alpha,\beta)\}=\Bbb R$$

I can't  say such a function does not exist, neither can I construct a example

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How is this a function from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$? $x$ seems to take on values in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Comment: $x$ takes on values between $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: Oops, thanks. My mistake

Comment: See the answer to this question for yet another example. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75589/open-maps-which-are-not-continuous

Comment: This was asked a few times here or on MO: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186427/, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454165/, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32126/ Also some answer to this question give also examples of functions like this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21812/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Conway base 13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) is one such function. From Wikipedia:

> $f$ takes as its value every real number somewhere within every open interval $(a,b)$.

The construction of the function is a little bit complicated. Refer to the wiki page for details.

Comment: I am really grateful for your prompt help!

Comment: @Clin Happy to help.

Answer (score 7):

My answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75589/open-maps-which-are-not-continuous/2933144#2933144) is precisely such a function, constructed in an easy way:

There is in fact a rather easy example of a function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that the image of every open set is $\mathbb R$: Let $(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb Z_+}$ be the binary decimal expansion of $x$, so that each $x_i\in\{0,1\}$. Let then
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^∞\frac{(−1)^{x_k}}k\quad \textrm{if the series converges}$$
$$f(x)=0\quad\textrm{otherwise.}$$
Since the harmonic series (or a tail of it) can be made to converge to any real number by changing signs in the appropriate way, this function has $f((a,b))=\mathbb R$ for any real $a,b$.

The harmonic series can be substituted with any other unbounded series where the summand goes to zero.

Comment: That's a quite old answer to an old question, but that's a great answer!

Comment: @Taladris Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Let $K$ be the Cantor set. For any $a, b\in \mathbb R,$ $a\ne 0,$ I'll also call $aK+b$ a Cantor set. Since $K$ has the cardinality of $\mathbb R,$ so do these other Cantor sets.

Note that if $U$ is any nonempty open subset of $\mathbb R,$ there exists a Cantor set inside of $U.$

Let $I_1,I_2, \dots$ be the open intervals in $\mathbb R$ with rational end points.

Claim: There are pairwise disjoint Cantor sets $K_1,K_2, \dots$ such that for each $n,$ $K_n \subset I_n.$

The claim is a nice exercise. Let's assume the result. For each $n$ there exists a bijection $f_n:K_n \to \mathbb R.$ Define $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ as follows. For each $n,$ set $f= f_n$ on $K_n.$ Set $f=0$ everywhere else.

Then $f$ has the desired property. Proof: Suppose $I$ is a nonempty open interval. Then $I_n\subset I$ for some $n.$ Since $K_n \subset I_n,$ we have $\mathbb R = f(K_n) \subset f(I_n) \subset f(I),$ and we're done.

Answer (score 3):

I find it easier to define one from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1)$.  You can use your favorite bijection to stretch each axis to $\Bbb R$.  Express $x \in (0,1)$ in base $3$, choosing the expansion  ending in all $2$'s for numbers which would terminate.  If $x$ has an infinite number of $2$'s in the expansion, set $f(x)=x$ and ignore it in the rest.  If $x$ has a finite number of $2$'s in the expansion, multiply it by $3^k$ so that the last two is just to the left of the ternary point.  The expansion is now all $0$'s and $1$'s.  Read it as a binary number and return that value.  To show it takes all values in an interval, let somebody give you a value $y$ it should take.  Express $y$ in binary.  Find an interval $(\frac {3m+2}{3^k},\frac {3m+3}{3^k})$ that is within the given interval for some naturals $m,k$. Express $\frac {3m+2}{3^k}$ in ternary and append the binary of $y$ on the right.  That will give you an $x$ such that $f(x)=y$  This needs a slight patch because some numbers are mapped to $1$, which is outside the range, so map them to $0.5$ and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for each $a<b$, $f[(a,b)]= \mathbb{R}$ is known as a strongly Darboux function. It can be constructed easily by transfinite induction (or more accurately, by the Recursion Theorem).

You may consult [Section 7.2](https://books.google.com/books?id=tTEaMFvzhDAC&pg=PA106) of the book "Set theory for the working mathematician" written by Krzysztof Ciesielski.