# How to characterize functions that map convex sets to convex sets?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

> What is a necessary and sufficient condition for the following? If $C$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then so is $f(C)$.

It's easy to find various sufficient conditions (I won't attempt an exhaustive list here), but I've been unable to find interesting necessary conditions.

If it helps, I'm happy to assume that $C$ is closed and/or bounded.

If a necessary and sufficient condition is known for $\mathbb{R}^n$, can it be extended to general vector spaces? Alternatively, if such a condition is unknown, could someone explain why the problem is difficult?

Comment: Do you want a characterisation of functions $f$ that map _all_ convex sets to convex sets? Because the way you phrased your question, it looks like you want a characterisation for a fixed $C$. But this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: And if the answer to my question is yes, I think it is necessary and sufficient that $f$ maps every straight line or line segment to a straight line, a line segment, or a point.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. I will edit for clarity.

Comment: @TonyK I'm having trouble showing necessity. Let $C$ be a line (segment) such that $f(C)$ is not a line (segment, point). If $n=1$, then it follows that $f(C)$ is not convex. But how to conclude for $n \geq 2$?

Comment: In full generality this question might be difficult: consider the existence of a space-filling curve from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^2$. Certainly all linear (affine) functions satisfy the property, as does any continuous function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$. Does anyone have a simple example of another function that satisfies the property?

Comment: @GregMartin Projections satisfy it (simple, but just a special case of linear maps). Another example I found, not quite as simple, is the "normalization" map $$r \mapsto \frac{1}{\sum_{i \in I} r_i}r,$$ where $I$ is a fixed subset if $\{1,...,n \}$.

Comment: @GregMartin But general continuous functions do not satisfy it, convexity is a strong property. I am not sure whether there is a space filling curve such that image of any interval is convex, it may be a good question for the start.
On the other hand, if we do not require continuity, every function which maps every open set to the whole $\mathbb R^n$ satisfies it.

Comment: @MirekOlšák: Are you sure about that last sentence? A straight line segment is a convex set; are you claiming that every function which maps every open set to the whole of $\mathbb R^n$ must also map straight line segments to the whole of  $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @TonyK Oh, you are right. I have forgotten about these flat convex sets at the moment. But there are still crazy mappings which map every segment to the whole $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Here is a counterexample: Let $f$ be a function that maps every open set to the whole of $\mathbb R^n$. Define $g(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ except when $x_1=0$, in which case $g=(0,\lfloor x_2\rfloor,\ldots,0)$. Then $g$ also maps every open set to the whole of $\mathbb R^n$, but the image of the (convex) line $x_1=0$ looks like (non-convex) $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: The question becomes interesting if you assume continuity and also that preimages of convex sets are convex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason there is no necessary condition is that there are quite pathological maps $f$ that satisfy the condition (as discussed in comments). As discussed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1828106), there exists a function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ that maps every nontrivial line segment onto $\mathbb{R}$. This can be composed with a surjection $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ (or a surjection of $\mathbb{R}$ onto a closed ball $B\subset \mathbb{R}^n$) to obtain a map $f$ such that $f(C)=\mathbb{R}^n$ for every convex set $C$ with more than one point. (Alternatively, $f(C)=B$ for any such $C$.)

This $f$ is quite terrible. There are no sensible function properties that it satisfies; yet, it preserves convexity. This is why we can't come up with a necessary property for convexity-preservation.

Comment: Thanks, this is a really nice answer. I'll have to study the answer you linked to a bit before accepting, but this is exactly the sort of answer I was looking for.