# Can connectedness preservation be used to define continuity of a function?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness

Suppose we have a function from a topological space (X, Tx) to (Y, Ty).

If for each subset of X that is connected (with respect to the induced topology from X) the image of that subset is also connected, does this imply the function must be continuous?

I am pretty sure the reverse of this is true b/c of the Main theorem of connectedness.

If it is true could this than be used as an alternate definition for continuity? It seems like a very intuitive definition to me b/c when I think of a continuous function I think of a mapping that doesn't 'break' apart things that are 'connected'.

Comment: I think not. Consider the topologists sine curve $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$. The only point of discontinuity of $f$ is $x=0$, but the image of every neighborhood of $x=0$ is the connected set $[-1,1]$.

Comment: As another counterexample, if $X$ is $\{ 0 \} \cup \{ 1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}^+ \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with the subspace topology, then every function with domain $X$ would satisfy this condition, but not every such function would be continuous.  (Equivalently, $X$ is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{N}$.)

Comment: @jeff But the function is not continuous at x = 0 therefore it is not a counterexample?

Comment: That's the point. My example passes your connected maps to connected statement, but is not continuous.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks @Jeff.

Comment: It can be even worse: A function can be discontinuous at every point of the real line but the image of each nondegenerate interval equal ${\mathbb R}$.

Comment: Is there an example of that @MoisheCohen?

Comment: Yes, there are such examples; I once worked out such examples myself and then found more at this site: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186427/function-whose-image-of-every-open-interval-is-infty-infty,  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790927/is-there-a-function-f-colon-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-such-that-every-non-empty-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to take this off the unanswered list:

Consider real functions $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$. The connected subsets of $\mathbb R$ are the intervals. A function satisfying the intermediate value property takes intervals to intervals, but there are highly discontinuous such functions, as noted in the comments. Such functions are often called [Darboux functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#Darboux_function).

Looking at the example of $\sin(\frac 1x)$, very close points (i.e lying in a small neighborhood of zero) are kept infinitely far apart in the graph of $x\mapsto \sin(\frac 1x)$.