# Mapping open intervals to dense sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, reference-request

Let $f$: $\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be badly behaved to the extent that the image of every $(a, b)$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Do such functions have a name? How much work on such functions has been done? What is a good (or not so good) reference? Thanks.

Comment: There are Borel measurable functions that map every $(a,b)$ onto $\mathbb R.$

Comment: Closely related is the following question: [Is there a different name for strongly Darboux functions?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137986/is-there-a-different-name-for-strongly-darboux-functions).