# Real numbers whose digits are the even digits of their squares

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, decimal-expansion

**The Context**

The origin of my question is my own answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3332275/continuity-of-a-strange-function), where the continuity of the function $f: [0,1) \to [0,1)$ that only preserves the odd digits of its input value is analyzed.

In this context, I will slightly modify the definition given there, as follows.

The function I am considering now is $f: [0,+\infty) \to [0,+\infty)$ that preserves only the **even** digits of the input. So if $x$ has decimal expansion

$$x = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_k 10^k,$$

then

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_{2k}10^{k}.$$

So for example

$$f(5\textbf{8}7\textbf{4}1\textbf{2}.7\textbf{8}0\textbf{3}4\textbf{0}5\textbf{1})=842.8301.$$

With a very similar approach to the one given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3332275/continuity-of-a-strange-function/3332351#3332351), it can be shown that $f$ is *continuous almost everywhere* (the only exception being the numbers whose least significant digit occupies an odd position), and right-continuous everywhere.

**Edit.** I am assuming, as in the original question, to adopt, in case of ambiguity, the *finite version of the number's decimal expansion*.

Note the self-similarity

$$f\left(10^{2k} x\right)=10^k f(x), \ \ \forall k\in \Bbb Z.$$

Below an approximate plot of the function $f$ in the range $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

[image]

Red dots represent points actually belonging to the graph of $f$. The yellow line represents the graph of 
$$s(x) = \sqrt x.$$
By self-similarity, a scaling of $10^{2k}$ of the $x$-axis and of $10^{-k}$ of the $y$-axis, for any $k\in \Bbb Z$, would give an exact replica of the given plot.

**Introductory Observation**

Aside from the trivial intersections between $f$ and $s$, that is all the points with coordinates

$$\left(10^{2k},10^k\right),$$

there are many other interesting intersections, such as (limiting ourselves to the range shown in the picture)

$$(0.25,0.5),$$
$$(0.36,0.6),$$
$$(0.0121,0.11),$$
and 'trikiest' ones, such as
$$(0.5776,0.76),$$
or even
$$(0.35295481,0.5941).$$

**The Question**

Is there any non-terminating decimal (or even irrational) $x$ such that 
$$y=f(x) = s(x),$$
that is, **is there any non-terminating decimal $y$ whose square contains - in the even positioned digits - the digits of the original number $y$?**

**Edit.** I emphasize again that no infinite sequences of $9$'s are allowed, since we are adopting the finite decimal expansion version of the number, if this ambuiguity arises.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding the question, but why aren't 5, 760, and 5941 solutions?

Comment: @rogerl you are correct, they **are** solutions. I only gave some examples of terminating decimals in the range of the picture. Infinite other solutions can be found from them, by self-similarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is on the *affirmative*.

Consider the sequence
\begin{eqnarray}
\alpha_0 &=& 1,\\
\alpha_1 &=& 10005,\\
\alpha_2 &=& 1000505,\\
\alpha_3 &=& 10005050005,\\
\alpha_4 &=& 1000505000500000005,\\
\dots & &,
\end{eqnarray}
where, for $n>1$, $\alpha_{n+1}$ is obtained from $\alpha_n$ by appending a sequence of $2^{n-1}-1$ zeros and then a $5$:
$$\alpha_{n+1} = \alpha_n \cdot 10^{2^{n-1}}+5.$$

Let us first show, by induction, that 
$$f\left(\alpha_n^2\right) = \alpha_n.\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
Suppose that \eqref{eq1} holds true for a given $n$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
f\left(\alpha_{n+1}^2\right) &=& f\left(\left(\alpha_n \cdot 10^{2^{n-1}}+5\right)^2\right)=\\
&=& f\left(\alpha_n^2\cdot 10^{2^n}+\alpha_n\cdot 10^{2^{n-1}+1}+25\right).
\end{eqnarray}
Note that

1. By induction and self-similarity of $f$, $$f\left(\alpha^2_n \cdot 10^{2^n}\right) = \alpha_n \cdot 10^{2^{n-1}};$$
2. For $n\geq 3$, the addition of the second term $\alpha_n\cdot 10^{2^{n-1}+1}$ does not modify any digits of the first term and *has $0$'s in every even position*;
3. The first and last term of the sum never interfere.

As a consequence

\begin{eqnarray}
f\left(\alpha_{n+1}^2\right) &=& f\left(\alpha_n^2\cdot 10^{2^n} + 25\right) =\\
&=&\alpha_n \cdot 10^{2^{n-1}} + 5=\\
&=& \alpha_{n+1}.
\end{eqnarray}

Consider now the sequence
\begin{eqnarray}
\beta_0 &=& 1,\\
\beta_1 &=& 1.005,\\
\beta_2 &=& 1.00505,\\
\vdots && \vdots\\
\beta_n &=& \alpha_n\cdot 10^{-2^n-2}.
\end{eqnarray}
The sequence $(\beta_n)$ is monotonic and upper bounded, and thus convergent in $\Bbb R$, and so is the sequence $(\beta_n^2)$.

Let

$$(\beta_n^2) \to \xi.$$

Clearly $\xi$ is a non-terminating decimal. Thus, as shown in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3332275/continuity-of-a-strange-function), $f(x)$ is continuous in $\xi$, and so is
$$ h(x) = f(x) - \sqrt x.$$

We therefore must have

$$\left(h\left(\beta^2_n\right)\right)\to h(\xi).$$

Since, by self-similarity of $h$, for each $n$
$$h\left(\beta_n^2\right)  = 0,$$
it must be
$$h(\xi) = 0,$$
that is
$$f(\xi) = \sqrt \xi.$$

---

**A little update**

- The same reasoning applies to the sequences $(5.0005, 5.000505, 5.0005050005,\dots)$, and $(6.0005, 6.000505, 6.0005050005,\dots)$.
- In the above mentioned sequences *any* digit $5$ can be replaced by a $0$, obtaining thus a *dense* set of intersection points on the right neighborhoods of $1$, $5$, and $6$.