# Continuous function with some properties plus everywhere surjective function must be everywhere surjective

Tags: set-theory, transfinite-recursion, transfinite-induction

Let me starts with some definitions : $f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R $ is everywhere surjective if $f[I]=\mathbb R$ for every nonempty open interval $I.$ $f$ is Darboux function if $f$ satisfies the intermediate value property. The cardinality of the family of all everywhere surjective from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ is $2^{c}.$ ($c$ is continuum). Also , notice that everywhere surjective is equivalent for saying  $f^{-1}(r)$ is dense for all $r\in\mathbb R.$ My question is:

Show that if $h$ is continuous function with the property that every nonempty open interval contains a nonempty subinterval on which $h$ is constant then $f+h$ is everywhere surjective for every everywhere surjective function $f.$

I have done a lot of construction functions like this by using transfinite induction but in this one I could not since the cardinality of everywhere surjective is $2^c$ and the cardinal of $\mathbb R$ is $c.$ I think, the transfinite induction would not work for this problem. I am trying to do it like that, BWOC, fix $f$ is everywhere surjective and assume $f+h$  is not everhwere surjective, that is, $(f+h)^{-1}(r)$ is not dense from some $r\in\mathbb R.$ Then there exists an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $ (f+h)^{-1}(r)\cap (a,b)=\emptyset$, that is, for all $x\in(a,b)$  $$f(x)+h(x)\neq r$$ $$ h(x)\neq r-f(x)$$ since $(c,d)\subset(a,b)$ such that $h(x)=y$ for all $x\in(c,d)$. So, $$f(x)\neq r-y$$ for all $x\in(c,d)$ which is impassable since $f(c,d)=\mathbb R.$ I checked my argument is correct

Comment: The title has absolutely nothing to do with the content, it seems. Also the tags.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I fixed the title but the tags I think okay since, this problem is related to set theory and using transfinite induction tool

Comment: I believe that if $f$ is everywhere surjective and $h$ is continuous (no other restriction on $h),$ then $f + h$ is everywhere surjective. Indeed, if the [cluster set](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3114828/13130) of $f(x)$ at $x=x_0$ is the extended real line (everywhere surjective function is equivalent to this being true for every $x_0)$ and $h(x)$ is continuous at $x=x_0,$ then I believe the cluster set of $(f+h)(x)$ at $x=x_0$ will also be the extended real line, and thus if $f$ has this property everywhere and $h$ is continuous everywhere, then $f+h$ will have this property everywhere.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, this is true in case no restriction on $h$. The problem actually related to big theorem By Natkanice (1990), see Prof  Ciesielski book page 108. If Ch true the there exists everywhere surjective function $f$ such that $f+h$ is not everywhere surjective for every nowhere -constant continuous function $h$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, I just  want to say my argument is correct

Comment: I was just curious where the terminology *everywhere surjective* is used. I have seen such functions under a different name: [Is there a different name for strongly Darboux functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/137986)